# get data from another add-on on Excel javascript api

Tags: javascript, excel, xml, office-js

I saved data on workbook on following code

```
export const storeSettingsToWorkbook = async (settingsType: Settings, storeData: 
 WorkbookModel) => {
  return Excel.run(async (context) => {
const originalXml = createXmlObject(storeData);
const customXmlPart = context.workbook.customXmlParts.add(originalXml);
customXmlPart.load("id");
await context.sync();

// Store the XML part's ID in a setting
const settings = context.workbook.settings;
settings.add(settingsTitles[settingsType], customXmlPart.id);
await context.sync();
 })
}
```

when i get data -it works normally.But when i want to get this data form another "add-in" on Excel- I cannot get this data

```
      const {settings} = context.workbook;
  const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet().load("items");
  const xmlPartIDSetting = settings.getItemOrNullObject(settingsTitles[settingsType]).load("value");

  await context.sync();


  if (xmlPartIDSetting.value) {
    const customXmlPart = context.workbook.customXmlParts.getItem(xmlPartIDSetting.value);
    const xmlBlob = customXmlPart.getXml();
    await context.sync()


    const parsedObject = parseFromXmlString(xmlBlob.value);
    const normalizedData = normalizeParsedData(parsedObject);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reaching us.
This is by design. Each addin has its own setting and cannot share with each other.
You can use 'context.workbook.properties.custom' as a workaround.
You can also use 'context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet().customProperties', but the two add-ins are required to be on the same worksheet.